# Write XSSF file row by row to output stream? (POI in java)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, outputstream

I have a huge amount of data which I would like to stream row by row. I thought calling workbook.write(stream) after changing the value of each row would append each write onto the output stream, but I was wrong. As it is, the file size suggests/matches the amount of rows I have, but there is only 1 row inside the file itself (which is the first row written).

Is there a way to accomplish this? Much like I would be able to using a text file?

I've taken a look at the BigGrid implementation, and it looks a bit overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't do a streaming write of the whole file in one go, the file format doesn't work like that. There are references between different parts of the file that preclude it. The file format just isn't like a CSV!

Instead, what you can do is hold a few small parts in memory, do a streaming write of the large parts of the spreadsheet to a temporary file, then re-assemble it in a low memory manner for output. To do that, look at the (fairly new) [SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) usermodel code in POI.

Comment: Just wondering...can't POI just directly write into output stream ? creating temp file is issue. especially on secure server

Comment: @JigarShah Excel formats like XLS and XLSX have back-and-forward references, so you can't just stream as you go. You need to buffer in memory, buffer on disk, or give up and use a streamable append-only format like CSV